# Datepicker plugin for birth date textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I've found a very easy to use datepicker called jquery datepicker. But the problem is when I want to use it for birth date. For example: my birth year is 1986 and the current year is 2013, then I need to click left arrow many times to decrease the months until I find 1986. It will be more troublesome if my birth year is 1960 or below.

Does anybody know any datepicker plugin that suitable for this? Perhaps a datepicker which year or month can be selected from dropbox or something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**In short:** you may do that bythe Restricting Datepicker section in the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year).

If you look down the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)  a bit, you'll see a "Restricting Datepicker" section. Use the dropdown to specify the "`Year dropdown shows last 20 years`" demo , and hit view source:

```
$("#restricting").datepicker({ 
    yearRange: "-20:+0", // this is the option you're looking for
    showOn: "both", 
    buttonImage: "templates/images/calendar.gif", 
    buttonImageOnly: true 
});
```

You'll want to do the same (obviously changing `-20` to `-100` or something).

**Option # 2:** is using the `changeMonth` and `changeYear` options of the api.

Try using 'yy' for the current year like:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({changeYear: true, yearRange : 'yy-50:yy+1'});
```

for more information view http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still have a hard time filling it with my birth date 2/24/1986. It is started on 2012, so I have to click left arrow 312 times. I As a normal user, will you spend your time to do that? Even though if I set the default birth year to 1986, it's still a problem for the one with birth year 1960 or below. That was my question in the first place.

Comment: Never mind that. I've just found out that jquery datepicker can display dropdown for its month and year. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: @HenryGunawan, as i have also stated in the answer you just need to use changeMonth and changeYear options.

Comment: @ElYusubov oh sorry I didn't see the changeYear part. I guess I was too sleepy when I replied you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: From the current year should look like yearRange : '-nn:+nn'.  So if from the current year I wanna go back 100 years for say a date of birth field, I just say: yearRange : '-100:+0'.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue, so in case someone else comes along with the same problem, I thought I'd post the solution.  It's in the answer above, but you have to read the comments to get all of it.

In the head:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '-100:+0'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
```

This will get you a date picker where the month is it's own dropdown, the year is it's own dropdown, and the year starts at today's year and goes back 100 years.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in datepicker call for the range you want to show in dropdown

```
yearRange: "1930:2025"
```

like this,

```
$( function() {
    $( "#celeb_dob" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1930:2025"
    });
  } );
```